# How to fix "cannot import name '__version__' from 'tensorflow.keras'"?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, keras-2, keras-rl

Trying to import [`DQNAgent`](https://keras-rl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/agents/dqn/) like this

```
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot import name '__version__' from 'tensorflow.keras'
```

The installed versions are:

`Tensorflow: 2.13.0`, `Keras: 2.13.1`, `Keras-rl2: 1.0.5`

I am using Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.

How can I fix this?

EDIT

If that helps to resolve the issue, this import

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras

print(keras.__version__)
```

causes

```
module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Answer (score 3):

In `rl/callbacks.py` change `from tensorflow.keras` to `from keras import __version__`. that should do the trick.

Comment: How about without modifying the source code?

Answer (score 3):

Find one solution without modifying the source code. cite from:*https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50372*

```
from keras import __version__
tf.keras.__version__ = __version__
```

and then:

```
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
```

Answer (score 0):

In ".../site-packages/rl/callbacks.py" change

`from tensorflow.keras import __version__ as KERAS_VERSION`

to

`from keras import __version__ as KERAS_VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to import:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import hdf5_format
```

The subsequent import error was:

```
cannot import name '__version__' from 'tensorflow.python.keras'
```

What worked for me was:

```
import tensorflow.python.keras as tf_keras
from keras import __version__
tf_keras.__version__ = __version__
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on google colab and faced similar problem. I added below lines of code to fix it.

```python
import tensorflow.keras as tf
from keras import __version__
tf.keras.__version__ = __version__
```

and then the code block where I was getting error

```python
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
```

fixed my error. Thanks for all the answers above as well.